# MySQL Syntax Error - During creating table

Tags: mysql, syntax, import

Do you have any idea what is wrong here?

```
CREATE TABLE `products_category` (
    `id` integer NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    `name` varchar(256) NOT NULL,
    `name_id` varchar(500) NOT NULL UNIQUE,
    `description` text,
    `keywords` text,
    `parent_id` integer,
    `image` varchar(100), 
    `spinned_name` VARCHAR
);
```

I get following error:
ERROR 1064 (42000) at line 2: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ')' at line 10

Comment: you forgot to provide data size for `varchar`  `spinned_name VARCHAR(200)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

Varchar was declared without any size so mention it.

```
CREATE TABLE `products_category` (
    `id` integer NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    `name` varchar(256) NOT NULL,
    `name_id` varchar(500) NOT NULL UNIQUE,
    `description` text,
    `keywords` text,
    `parent_id` integer,
    `image` varchar(100), 
    `spinned_name` VARCHAR(50) //no size here
);
```

Comment: Explain what you changed.

Comment: Answear is correct! :) Thanks a lot. He added size of spinned_name

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
`spinned_name` VARCHAR
```

To

```
`spinned_name` VARCHAR(100)
```